# correlation name not found on SQL Anywhere

Tags: t-sql, sql-function, sqlanywhere

I have two tables called *Employees* and *Salarygroup*. PersonalID is the primary key of *Employees* and *SalaryID* is the primary key of Salarygroup. Inside the Employees table there is one more row called *StartDat*, which has date data  type and tracks down the date when the employee started working at the company. Moreover, *AmountInEuros* is the salary that an employee gets every month and it has a numeric data type

I need to make a function, which count the total amount of money, that the employee has recieved so far from the company, but when I input the PersonalID I get an error saying *Correlation name 'Salarygroup' not found.

Could someone helo me understand why this is happening?

```
  ALTER FUNCTION "dba"."countTotalAmountOfMoney"(@PersonalID int)
   RETURNS int
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @totalAmountOfMoney int;
   SELECT  @totalAmountOfMoney = g.AmountInEuros * DATEDIFF(month, g.StartDat, 
        '2019-01-16') 
   FROM dba.Employees 
   Inner Join dba.Salarygroup s
   ON   dba.Employees.SalaryId = dba.Salarygroup.SalaryId

   RETURN @totalAmountOfMoney;
END
```

Comment: Not sure, but i would guess because you gave it an alias, so you should refer to the alias: `dba.Employees.SalaryId = s.SalaryId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the table an alias, so you need to use it.  I would recommend using aliases for all the tables:

```
DECLARE @totalAmountOfMoney int;

SELECT @totalAmountOfMoney = s.AmountInEuros * DATEDIFF(month, e.StartDat, '2019-01-16') 
FROM dba.Employees e INNER JOIN
     dba.Salarygroup s
     ON e.SalaryId = s.SalaryId
WHERE e.personalID = @PersonalID;
```

Note that the `g` alias is not defined in your query.  `StartDat` comes from `Employees`, so I changed that to `e`.  I am guessing that `AmountInEuros` comes from `s`.

Comment: I corrected it but I keep on getting an error saying SELECT returns more than one row. Do u understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgotten to refer the second table using the Alias 's' you created:

```
ALTER FUNCTION "dba"."countTotalAmountOfMoney"(@PersonalID int)
   RETURNS int
   AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @totalAmountOfMoney int;
   SELECT  @totalAmountOfMoney = g.AmountInEuros * DATEDIFF(month, g.StartDat, 
        '2019-01-16') 
   FROM dba.Employees 
   Inner Join dba.Salarygroup s
   ON   dba.Employees.SalaryId = s.SalaryId

   RETURN @totalAmountOfMoney;
END
```